# GKE NGINX Ingress - no data in Stackdriver

Tags: nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have successfully set up an NGINX ingress on GKE. It's been handling traffic for a while, so all good there.

However, it does not seem to be reporting metrics data to Stackdriver. I am not sure if it should be doing this out-of-the-box or if I have to configure something (perhaps this?: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/nginx). The instructions for this plug-in are clear but do not seem compatible with the layout of the NGINX pod (i.e.: can't run `sudo` commands, directory structure is different, etc).

This is what I see when I try to add a chart to show NGINX connections in my Stackdriver dashboard.

[image: Active Connections Metric in Stackdriver]

If anyone could shed light on how I can get GKE-deployed NGINX ingresses to report metrics to Stackdriver I'd be appreciative! :)

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you choose wrong `Resourse type` because `GCE VM Instance` you should use for `A virtual machine instance hosted in Google Compute Engine (GCE)` and here you have `GKE-deployed NGINX ingresses`.

**EDIT** I think you should use this [guide](https://medium.com/uptime-99/kubernetes-hpa-autoscaling-with-custom-and-external-metrics-da7f41ff7846) as an example to get metrics you want in Stackdriver.

**EDIT 2** You can find more information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/monitoring-apps-running-on-multiple-gke-clusters-using-prometheus-and-stackdriver) and [here](https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank you for this; it looks like exactly what I am after. One problem though... after setting up the `prometheus-to-sd` sidecar I get this error: "listen tcp :6061: bind: address already in use". Is that because Prometheus is already active in my cluster?

Comment: As I can see at https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations port `6061` doesn't look like some `Prometheus` port. Also, here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/blob/master/prometheus-to-sd/kubernetes/prometheus-to-sd-kube-state-metrics.yaml I see port `6060`, not `6161`. I've deployed to my test cluster NGINX ingress and test app as it's shown here https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke, External Metric server and sidecar pod. All the components run in `Workloads` and I found no errors in `Logging Viewer`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too... doesn't seem to make much sense. The other thing I see is messages like this in the `kube-state-metrics` logs: "Failed to list *v1beta1.VolumeAttachment: volumeattachments.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "volumeattachments" in API group "storage.k8s.io" at the cluster scope". I wonder if I have a permissions issue that is preventing data coming over?

Comment: Look at RBAC permission in this example https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke. I've installed Tiller with RBAC support. More information about RBAC here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/ .